# Double sum of natural numbers squared

Tags: summation, discrete-calculus

I am wondering how you would compute a double sum such as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{p}\sum_{m=0}^n (m+n)^2$$

I understand methods for finding closed forms of sums using Discrete Calculus from reading Concrete Mathematics where for example one could view $\sum_{m=1}^p m^2 = \sum_{m=1}^p \Delta(\frac{1}{3}m^{\underline{3}}+\frac{1}{2}m^{\underline{2}})$ and then using the fact the the sum telescopes. I run into trouble applying that approach here because I get terms such as $(2n+1)^{\underline{2}}$. Is it possible to realize this as the forward difference of something? If it's not then what is a way to evaluate the sum?

Comment: I am not sure how helpful this is but your sum can be shown to be equal to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^p [n^2+(n+1)^2+\cdots+(2n)^2]$.

Comment: Another method would be to develop : $(n + m)^2 = n^2 + 2nm + m^2$. Each sum of squares is known, and the sum with term $nm$ is also known I think, but otherwise juste use the trick of @ShyamalSayak

Comment: @eti902 Good point.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7Bp%7D%5Csum_%7Bm%3D0%7D%5En(m%2Bn)%5E2%24&p=1), there's the similar [exact closed form expression](/q/2994151), where the [answer](/a/2994285) shows the expression is equivalent to $\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n(i+j)^2$, i.e., where the upper limit of both summations is the same, fixed value of $n$, while only the outer summation of yours has a fixed value of $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm offhand unaware how to determine the summations using forward differences. Instead, with the Faulhaber's formula [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples), and [eti902's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752057/double-sum-of-natural-numbers-squared#comment10084959_4752057) suggestion, we get for the inner summation

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=0}^{n}(m^2+2mn+n^2) & = \sum_{m=0}^{n}m^2 + 2n\sum_{m=0}^{n}m + n^2\sum_{m=0}^{n}1 \\
& = \left(\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}\right)+2n\left(\frac{n^2+n} {2}\right) + n^2(n+1) \\
& = \left(\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}\right)+ (n^3+n^2) + (n^3+n^2) \\
& = \frac{7n^3}{3} + \frac{5n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Alternatively, based on [ShyamalSayak's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752057/double-sum-of-natural-numbers-squared/4752078#comment10084956_4752057) suggestion, using $i = m+n$, we instead get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=0}^{n}(m+n)^2 & = \sum_{i=n}^{2n}i^2 \\
& = \sum_{i=0}^{2n}i^2 - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2 \\
& = \left(\frac{(2n)^3}{3} + \frac{(2n)^2}{2} + \frac{2n}{6}\right) - \left(\frac{(n-1)^3}{3} + \frac{(n-1)^2}{2} + \frac{n-1}{6}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{8n^3}{3} + 2n^2 + \frac{n}{3}\right) - \left(\frac{n^3-3n^2+3n-1}{3} + \frac{n^2-2n+1}{2} + \frac{n-1}{6}\right) \\
& = \frac{7n^3}{3} + \frac{5n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

In either case, the outer summation is then

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{p}\left(\frac{7n^3}{3} + \frac{5n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}\right) & = \frac{7}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{p}n^3 + \frac{5}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{p}n^2 + \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{p}n \\
& = \frac{7}{3}\left(\frac{p^4}{4}+\frac{p^3}{2}+\frac{p^2}{4}\right) + \frac{5}{2}\left(\frac{p^3}{3}+\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{p}{6}\right) + \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{p^2+p}{2}\right) \\
& = \frac{7p^4}{12} + 2p^3 + \frac{23}{12}p^2 + \frac{p}{2} \\
& = \frac{p(p+1)(7p^2+17p+6)}{12} \\
& = \frac{p(p+1)(p+2)(7p+3)}{12}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$